# Displaying third tier submenus properly with css only menu

Tags: css, hover, position, submenu

I am developing a new site, and am having problems with the css menu. It is easier to explain by example:  Here is the link of the site: http://www.webau.net/CSFF/index.asp

Under the "Home" parent menu item, I have the following configuration:

```
Top level menu (parent)
    Submenu 1 (child 1)
        Submenu 2 (grandchild 1)
    Submenu 3 (child 2)
    Submenu 4 (child 3)
```

Instead it appears on the page like this where the grandchild 1 looks like it takes the place of the child 2 menu:

```
Top level menu (parent)
    Submenu 1 (child 1)
    Submenu 2 (grandchild 1)
    Submenu 4 (child 3)
```

I can see a slight offset on the listing of Submenu 2.. which makes me think it is an attempt to display the grandchild inappropriately.

So I am assuming I have two problems..

First is that the third tier menu (grandchild submenu 2) is displaying at the same time the second tier menus (child submenus 1, 3, 4) display when you hover over the parent menu item.

And second is that for some reason the grandchild submenu 2 item is displacing (laying ontop of) the child submenu 3.

I think problem two will be fixed when I correct the display of the grandchild submenu.

Can someone help me figure out how to add new css code to deal with the third tier or multi- tier menus .. so they are hidden until their own parent is hovered, and to then display to the right of it's parent's submenu column?

Thanks again for your help.
SunnyOz

For your convenience:
HTML Code:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <div id="navsection">  
        <ul>
            <li id="navactive"><a class="current" href="#">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">submenu 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">submenu 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">submenu 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">submenu 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><... rest of menu items not needed for example>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#navcontainer 
{
    width: 711px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto; /*Center container on page*/
    clear: both;
    background-color: #129F9F;
    border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 

    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #16ACAC 0%, #0D6F6F 100%);

    /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #16ACAC 0%, #0D6F6F 100%);

    /* Opera */ 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #16ACAC 0%, #0D6F6F 100%);

    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #16ACAC), color-stop(1, #0D6F6F));

    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #16ACAC 0%, #0D6F6F 100%);

    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #16ACAC 0%, #0D6F6F 100%); 
}
#navsection
{
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
}
#navsection ul
{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 35px;  /* padding on left to get nav menu to center.. since it has a float left to make it display properly*/
    list-style: none;
}
#navsection ul li
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 2px solid #129F9F;
    float: left;
}
#navsection ul li.navcontact  /* to stop right border at end of nav line */
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: none;
    float: left;
}
#navsection ul li a
{
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
#navsection > ul > li > a:hover, #navsection  > ul > li:hover > a  
{  
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #EAA339;
    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0D6F6F 0%, #16ACAC 100%);

    /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0D6F6F 0%, #16ACAC 100%);

    /* Opera */ 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0D6F6F 0%, #16ACAC 100%);

    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #0D6F6F), color-stop(1, #16ACAC));

    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0D6F6F 0%, #16ACAC 100%);

    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0D6F6F 0%, #16ACAC 100%); 
}

#navsection > ul > li > a.current:hover, #navactive a.current:link, #navactive a:visited, #navactive > ul  li  a:hover, #navsection a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #EAA339;
    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0D6F6F 0%, #16ACAC 100%);

    /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0D6F6F 0%, #16ACAC 100%);

    /* Opera */ 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0D6F6F 0%, #16ACAC 100%);

    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #0D6F6F), color-stop(1, #16ACAC));

    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0D6F6F 0%, #16ACAC 100%);

    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0D6F6F 0%, #16ACAC 100%); 
}

#navsection ul li ul
{
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#navsection ul li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navsection ul li:hover li
{
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
}
#navsection ul li:hover li
{
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 24px;
    background: #54C4C4;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
}
#navsection ul li:hover li a
{
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
}
#navsection ul li li a:hover
{
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 24px;
    color:#EAA339;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 issues here.

1. You are displaying all `<ul/>` elements that exist below a hovered `<li/>`.
   Change `#navsection ul li:hover ul` to `#navsection ul li:hover > ul` to select the immediate child only
2. You are setting the position of each drop level to be the same.
   Try adding something like `#navsection ul ul ul { top: 1em; left: 140px; }`, this will stop the grandchild obscuring the child.
3. You're `title` attributes are negatively affecting your navigation.
   I'd remove them entirely as they do not add any real beneficial information to the link **and** obscure the menu items making the navigation difficult to use.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you, thank you!!  I used all your advice, and it works perfectly now!  I am afraid to push my luck, but I was wondering if you could help me with two other items.  I have uploded the changes to [link] (http://www.webau.net/CSFF/index.asp) again, but moved the drop down menus to the "What about CSFF" tab now.  I have added 3 tiers of submenus. First question: As you can see if you hover over submenu 2, a third level of submenu is displayed, but it is positioned 1em down from the top of the previous submenu's column, not 1em down from it's own parents location.  Can that be fixed?

Comment: Second question: Is there a way to make the submenus be the same size as the max content in it's own group of submenus?  I have all submenus sized at 200px, and it works for the first submneu.. but in my example it is too long for the rest. (Also see submenu from "Make a Donation".)  I obviously want the submenus to be uniform sized to their own submenu group, but they can be different from other submenu groups.  Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: no worries :). 1st new question: remove `margin: 0` from `#navsection ul li:hover > ul` and change `#navsection ul ul ul { top: 1em; }` to `#navsection ul ul ul { margin-top: -1em; }`. 2nd question: You can but it will involve more markup. Add a class to each first-level item in the navigation and use this class to set that items sub-menu width AND offset (e.g. `left:205px`). You need to know the menu width to set the offset which is why you need the classes. Hope that helps :) If you have further question please start a new thread; we want the questions to be discoverable by other users

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I was successful in moving over my submenus to be relative to their own parent perfectly.  I am still having problems figuring out how to fix the uniform size fit to text size.. but I'll keep working on it.  Thanks for your help.